# read from file line by line , multiple match in file possible

Tags: python, file, readlines

I am reading form a file and trying to produce the following:

1. Search the file to find the "temperature", where "temperature" can occur several times in file
2. Organize the data: produce 4 lists:

   - 1st list: list_planes_r (name of the planes): [plane_r_01, plane_r_02,  plane_r_03, plane_r_04]
   - 2nd list: temp_plane_r (temperature values): [54, 50, 52, 10]
   - 3rd list: list_planes_f: [plane_f_01, plane_f_02,  plane_f_03, plane_f_04]
   - 4th list: temp_plane_f: [1254, 1354, 1454, 1554]

I am always running in the problem of having to split a list, which of course I am not allowed to do.

I did as below:

```
with open ('test_reading_file.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
list_lines = []
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
 if   ('  temperature') in line:
        list_lines.append(lines[index+1: index+5]
```

My toy file 'test_reading_file.txt'

```
  temperature
-------
 plane_r_01          54
 plane_r_02          50
 plane_r_03          52
 plane_r_04          10


  co
-------
 plane_r_01          54
 plane_r_02          54
 plane_r_03          54
 plane_r_04          54

  temperature
-------
 plane_f_01          1254
 plane_f_02          1354
 plane_f_03          1454
 plane_f_04          1454
```

Update: pictures[image: current_output]

Comment: can you show us the output of your code to better understand what you need to do ?

Comment: I have shown the output of the code. The 2nd image kinda shows  the desired output (having the desired lists I can do this  with pandas)

Comment: why is splitting list not ideal again ?

Comment: I thought python lists are not "splitable". My problem is now how can I end up with "plane_r_01", 54 instead of ["plane_r_01", 54]. I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the shorter version:

```
list_planes = []
list_temperatures = []
[list_planes.append([sub.split()[0] for sub in content]) for content in list_lines]
[list_temperatures.append([sub.split()[1] for sub in content]) for content in list_lines]

list_planes_r, list_planes_f = list_planes
temp_plane_r, temp_plane_f = list_temperatures
```

Comment: this comes after what you've done there might be simpler ways but this works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as I wanted. I have accepted your answer, so only if you have extra time: you mention this whole thing can be done in a simpler manner. Can you give me some hints: i did it this way because I didn't know better.

Comment: it's only reducing the several lines of looping into a single line, complexity wise it would stay the same.

Comment: @Silvia The shorter neater version is posted ^

Answer (score 1):

I have not completely clear what do you want, but my best guess is that you want two list (say `planes` and `temperatures`) so that you can do

```
for plane, temperature in zip(planes, temperatures):
    ...
```

The code that I produced according to this guess is

```
planes, temperatures = [], []
with open('...') as f:

    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'temperatures':
            next(f)  # skip a line
            for n in range(4):
                p, t = next(f).strip().split()
                planes.append(p)
                temperatures.append(t)
```

I have checked the results.

The code works because a file object (here `f`) is an *iterator* and we can advance inside the iterator, consuming the iterator, using the `next` builtin.

The use case in which you scan a file and read some lines when you find a keyword is a canonical example of using `next`; not using `next` means using a flag and raising/clearing it as you enter/exit from the *interesting* zone...

Comment: Thanks for contributing. It's more compact +elegant, and I have checked and with little modifications i can get also to what I wanted.